# Global Variable returning to 0.0 after completion of an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, variables, android-asynctask, global

The main part of this question is, when I run this code, the TextViews latitudeTextView and longitudeTextView get updated correctly, therefore the global variable are being change to the correct values. But when i try to access them again after going an asynctask, they are set to 0.0, 0.0? Shouldn't they stay as the same values after onPostExecute ends?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Weather>{

    private static final String GOOGLE_CONVERTER = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";

    private static final String GOOGLE_KEY = "AIzaSyBtt8yaXoRvLTkJHUXrhl5pQaLxomReHIA";

    public static final int LOADER_ID = 0;

    String jsonResponse = "";
    private String address;

    private TextView latitudeTextView;
    private TextView longitudeTextView;
    private TextView summaryTextView;
    private TextView tempuratureTextView;
    private TextView timezoneTextView;
    private TextView textTextView;

    private double latitude = 0.0;
    private double longitude = 0.0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        latitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        longitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
        summaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.summaryTextView);
        tempuratureTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperatureTextView);
        timezoneTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timezoneTextView);
        textTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);

        final EditText addressEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_address);
        Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                address = addressEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                address = "5121+Paddock+Court+Antioch+Ca+94531";
                String fullUrl = GOOGLE_CONVERTER + "?address=" + address + "&key=" + GOOGLE_KEY;
                new getlongAndLat().execute(fullUrl);
                textTextView.setText(latitude + "");
                //Log.e("TAG", latitude + " " + longitude);
              //  getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, MainActivity.this);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public android.content.Loader<Weather> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new WeatherAsyncTaskLoader(this, latitude, longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader<Weather> loader, Weather data) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader<Weather> loader) {

    }


    public class getlongAndLat extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.connect();
                Log.e("TAG", connection.getResponseCode() + "");

                if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //trouble closing input stream
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            extractJsonResponse(jsonResponse);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            latitudeTextView.setText(latitude + "");
            longitudeTextView.setText(longitude + "");
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }

    private void extractJsonResponse(String jsonResponse) {
        try {
            JSONObject rootJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            JSONArray nodeResultsArray = rootJsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            JSONObject nodeFirstObject = nodeResultsArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject nodeGeometryObject = nodeFirstObject.getJSONObject("geometry");
            JSONObject nodeLocation = nodeGeometryObject.getJSONObject("location");

            latitude = nodeLocation.getDouble("lat");
            longitude = nodeLocation.getDouble("lng");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        return output.toString();

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you talking about this line `textTextView.setText(latitude + "")`? and here you're getting the latitude zero?

Comment: It's not clear where your problem is, but one potential problem is that you set a `private double` field in one thread and then read it in another thread with no `volatile` or `synchronized` keyword and no other intervening memory barrier. What makes you think you will read an up-to-date value from that field rather than an old value from a register or a cache line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code doInBackground(), you are calling extractJsonResponse() method before return statement. In extractJsonResponse(), you are getting lat and long and setting those to Global variables as mentioned in your code

```
JSONObject nodeLocation = nodeGeometryObject.getJSONObject("location");

    latitude = nodeLocation.getDouble("lat");
    longitude = nodeLocation.getDouble("lng");
```

I am sure that you are getting those zero values from Json object. You need to verify this thing at your end